# Gem with models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, paperclip

I created a Gem with models (actually, extracted it from the main project) to share amongst the projects we have in our platform.

We have dozens of models, so instead of requiring them one by one, I wrote the following code:

```
Gem.find_files("my_gem/models/*.rb").each { |path| require path }
```

I access one of the projects that has my_gem in the gem file and running `rails c` I get the following output:

```
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:50:in `method_missing': undefined method `has_attached_file' for #<Class:0x007fad4b93ccb8> (NoMethodError)
```

One of my models is using the gem paperclip, what is weird is:

1. If I remove the line declared above to load all the models
   automatically, `rails c`  runs fine
2. If I try to include onlye the model that uses paperclip `require
   "my_gem/models/paperclip_model"` I receive the same error

So then I change my gem to not load any model, and when I try to reference any model from rails console, it says the class is not loaded, but then I run `Gem.find_files("my_gem/models/*.rb").each { |path| require path }` or `require "my_gem/models/paperclip_model"` 'they work perfectly and I am able to work with the model.

Has any of you seen the same issue?

Comment: Where in your Rails code are you calling `Gem.find_files("my_gem/models/*.rb").each { |path| require path }` from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that changing `require` for `autoload` solved the problem

I changed `Gem.find_files("my_gem/models/*.rb").each { |path| require path }`

for

```
Gem.find_files("my_gem/models/*.rb").each do |f| 
  filename = File.basename(f, '.*')
  class_name_symbol = filename.classify.to_sym
  autoload class_name_symbol, "my_gem/models/#{filename}"
end
```

and now it is working.

Comment: thank you for sharing this, has helped me a lot :)  strange that require did not work though

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like one of the models in your gem depends on Paperclip, but you don't explicitly set it as a dependency. So what's happening is that if your models get loaded *before* paperclip gets loaded, you'll see the `UndefinedMethod` error for `has_attached_file`.

If you use your models in a Rails application which has paperclip as a dependency, and you load those models *after* the console (or server) has spun up, Paperclip will be present, so you won't see this error.

The solution is to explicitly add paperclip as a dependency in your gemspec, something like:

```
s.add_dependency('paperclip')
```

Assuming that this gem will always be used in the context of a Rails application, this should work. If not, you *might* also need to add the following line to the top of your models that use paperclip:

```
require "paperclip"
```